# Regex to find internal match between two characters

Tags: java, regex

Environment: Java

I want to match characters between two string, here is an example

```
foo <bar <foo@bar.com> xoo <xoo@bar.com>
```

I need two String: foo@bar.com and xoo@bar.com

I am using this regex:

> <(.*?)>

But this is returning me

```
bar <foo@bar.com
```

and

```
xoo@bar.com
```

So basically I want to match characters between two Strings, but I need the internal ones.

Any help is highly appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this negation based regex for matching:

```
<[^<>]*>
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/mT2pQ3

OR using lookarounds to give you emails only:

```
(?<=<)[^<>]*(?=>)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following regex:

```
<([^<>]+)>
```

The capturing group should return the string you want.

The problem with your regex is that you are failing to take into account the possibility that you could encounter *another* `<` character after the starting `<`. Your regex, as it stands, matches `<` and then zero or more of any character (non-greedy) followed by `>`. But the `.*` part will also match another `<`. So you want to basically match a string that starts with `<`, then only contains characters *other than* `<` or `>`, and finally ends with `>`.

Here's some sample code:

```
String s = "foo <bar <foo@bar.com> xoo <xoo@bar.com>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^<>]+)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

You can see this in action in Java [here](http://ideone.com/gat1cM).

Answer (score 1):

<([^<>]*?)> will do the trick.

Since "." mathces ANYTHIN (also "<" and ">") "bar ".
By using "[^<>]" you say anything (like ".") BUT the charecters within the squares - after the hat.

A great site to test your RegEx is http://www.regexr.com/ :)