# java regex find match between commas

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a match between commas if it contains a specific string.

so far i have `,(.*?myString.?*),`

Obviously this finds all the input between the first comma in the entire input and the first comma after the string i want. How do i reference the comma immediately before the string that i want?

Edit: i also want to find the match that occurs after a specific set of characters

ie. occurs after (fooo)

dsfdsdafd,safdsa,gfdsgd**theMatch**fdsgfd,dsafdsa,dsfoooafd,safdsa,gfhhhgd**theMatch**fhhhfd,dsafdsa

returns gfhhhgd**theMatch**fhhhfd, not gfdsgd**theMatch**fdsgfd

Comment: Don't match on `.` *(wildcard)*, match on anything but `,`, i.e. `,([^,]*myString[^,]*),`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *regex* should do it :

```
[^,]+theMatch.*?(?=,)
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iXb67p/1)**

**Java** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/n0HuVK) )

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class RegEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "dsfdsdafd,safdsa,gfdsgdtheMatchfdsgfd,dsafdsa";
        String r = "[^,]+theMatch.*?(?=,)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());  // gfdsgdtheMatchfdsgfd
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

use this *regex* `fooo.*?([^,]+theMatch.*?)(?=,)` [**demo**](https://ideone.com/tj3tsy)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, i was wondering if you could help with one more condition.  Let's say there's are multiple occurrences of the string i want. Is there a way to match the one that occurs after a certain set of characters (not necessarily immediately after just that it occurs after the string in general)

Comment: i updated my post with an example, hopefully that's clear enough

Comment: great, thanks again man. I definitely need to read up on regex

Answer (score 2):

You are finding too much because `.*` will include the comma.

You need the following regular expression: `,([^,]*myinput[^,]*),`

`[^,]*` basically says find all non-comma characters.

I would suggest the following code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "dsfdsdafd,safdsa,myinput,dsafdsa";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",([^,]*myinput[^,]*),");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        if(m.find()) {

            System.out.println(m.group(0));
            // prints out ",myinput,"

            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            // prints out "myinput"
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a StackOverflow question that is basically the same with some very good answers associated: 
[Regex to find internal match between two characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886949/regex-to-find-internal-match-between-two-characters?rq=1)

For more on regular expressions in Java look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

If you want the position of the comma proceeding your input string use the following code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "dsfdsdafd,safdsa,myinput,dsafdsa";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",([^,]*myinput[^,]*),");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        if(m.find()) {

            System.out.println(str.indexOf(m.group(0)));

            // prints out "16"
        }

    }
}
```

By feeding the match of the regular expression into the String Method `indexOf(` you are able to locate the position of the start of your string.

Edit:

To find the occurrence of a string following another string, simply modify the regex to: `fooo.*,([^,]*theMatch[^,]*),`

`fooo.*` will greedily consume all characters between `fooo` and the start of your match.

Example code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "dsfdsdafd,safdsa,gfdsgdtheMatchfdsgfd,dsafdsa,dsfoooafd,safdsa,gfhhhgdtheMatchfhhhfd,dsafdsa";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("fooo.*,([^,]*theMatch[^,]*),");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        if(m.find()) {

            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            // prints out: gfhhhgdtheMatchfhhhfd
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to use a pattern that cannot match your delimiter in place of `.`.  In this case, you need that only at the front of the pattern; you can use a reluctant quantifier at the back as you already do (though you've misspelled it).  For example:

```
,([^,]*myString.*?),
```